# Given a spectrum, how to deduce the space and the operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Suppose $\sigma(T)=\{e^{\frac{i}{n}}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0,1\}$. How can I deduce an appropriate Banach space $X$ and compact operator $T$ such that this is true?

Obviously, $\lambda\in\sigma(T)\iff \mathscr{R}(T-\lambda I)\ne X\text{ or }T-\lambda I$ is not injective.

Since $\sigma_{p}(T)\subset\sigma (T)$, where $\sigma_{p}(T)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}:T-\lambda I\text{ is not injective }\}$, i.e. the set of eigenvalues, and each $x\in\mathscr{N}(T-\lambda I)$ must satisfy the equation
$$Tx=\lambda x.$$

Clearly $0$ and $1$ cannot be in the same point spectrum. However, this does not rule them out of being in the spectrum. Ultimately, I was wondering if someone had an effective method for determining such $X$ and $T$?

Comment: The only point that can be an accumulation point of the spectrum of a compact operator is $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, this is stated for example a result in Rudin's 'Functional Analysis', Theorem 4.25 (c), but I don't understand the relevance?

Comment: For your set $\sigma(T)$, the one accumulation point it has is $1$. Hence it cannot be the spectrum of a _compact_ operator. No problem finding a _bounded_ linear operator with that spectrum, however.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, but I suppose it doesn't really answer the broader question: "given a spectrum, how to deduce the space and the operator?". Suppose, for example that $\sigma(T)=\{8/n^{2}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, then this has one accumulation point; which is indeed 0.

Comment: The answer to the broader question is "you can't deduce the space and the operator, there are many different spaces and operators producing that spectrum (if there is any)". You can get every nonempty compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ as the spectrum of a multiplication operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Does this assertion hold true for the point spectrum?

Answer (score 0):

$X=l^2$ and $T$ the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries from $\sigma (T)$